# Fixing TypeError: object of type '...' has no len

Tags: python, object

This is my code.

```
def areSimilar(item1,item2):
    if(len(item1) == len(item2)):
        for i in range(len(item1)):
            if isinstance(item1[i],list) and isinstance(item2[i],list):
                if areSimilar(item1[i],item2[i])==False:
                    return False

            else:
                if type(item1[i]) != type(item2[i]):
                    return False

    else:
        return False
    return True
```

Here are examples of what is want to work.

```
>>> print(areSimilar(True, False)) #items are same type and are not lists
True
>>> print(areSimilar(1, 'a') #items are different types
False
>>> print(areSimilar([],[]))                      
True                        
>>> print(areSimilar([],[3])) #list lengths differ
False
>>> print(areSimilar([3.0],[3]))  #lists of same length but index 0 items  are not similar
False
>>> print(areSimilar([5],[3]))  #lists of same length and corresponding lists items are similar
True
>>> print(areSimilar([1,2,['a','b']],[3,4, [1,2,3]])) #items at index 2 are not similar
False
>>> print(areSimilar([1,2,[False, 'b']],[3, 4, [True, 'hello']]))
True
>>> print(areSimilar([[[[],[2],[],['hi', [0]]]]], [[[[],[-2],[],['bye', [1]]]]]))
True
>>> print(areSimilar([[[[],[2],[],['hi', [0]]]]], [[[[],[-2],[],['bye', 0]]]]))
False
```

All of them work except the first two. Where I get

> "TypeError: object of type 'bool/int' has no len"

how do i fix this?

Comment: Change your control flow to handle things that don't have an `ob_size` or implement `__len__`?

Comment: Obviously an int or a bool don't have a notion of length. So your function should not try to call `len` on the arguments until it's determined that the thing being passed in are valid things to call `len` on.

Comment: Or use a try/except block to deal with the issue when it arises

Answer (score 0):

Just add guards that will convert type to list.

```
def areSimilar(item1,item2):
    if not getattr(item1, '__len__', False):
       item1 = [item1]
    if not getattr(item2, '__len__', False):
       item2 = [item2]
    if(len(item1) == len(item2)):
        for i in range(len(item1)):
            if isinstance(item1[i],list) and isinstance(item2[i],list):
                if areSimilar(item1[i],item2[i])==False:
                    return False

            else:
                if type(item1[i]) != type(item2[i]):
                    return False

    else:
        return False
    return True
```

However solution looks messy and overall function design requires changes.